# Is Bot Service on Azure no longer using CSX files?

Tags: azure, botframework

I've just created a bot service on Azure and it looks completely different from what I got last time. Back then I ended up with a bunch of CSX files. Now it has created what looks like a full blown ASP.NET app (see screenshot).

How many different backends are there these days? C#, CSX and NodeJS or is CSX no longer a thing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. It depends on the plan you are using for the bot. For my example above I used regular plan. If (during creation) "consumption plan" is selected, the bot will be based on CSX files. This behaviour is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/azure-bot-service-debug-bot

> The consumption plan serverless C# environment in Azure Bot Service
>   has more in common with Node.js than a typical C# application because
>   it requires a runtime host, much like the Node engine. In Azure, the
>   runtime is part of the hosting environment in the cloud, but you must
>   replicate that environment locally on your desktop.

Comment: @CSharpRocks trust me, I have been using SO for a while and thus know that the own answer can only be accepted after two days :-)

Comment: I've been using SO for a while and I didn't know that.  I also didn't know that you knew that :-)